# Removing text from an image in a rough but quick fashion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, images

I often find myself in a situation where I'd like to check how an image would look like without the text embedded in it. I'm not interested in a neat result, just something rough but super quick and easy.

Is there a plugin or something to achieve just that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually, text is a smooth, solid color, which makes it easy to select with the good old-fashioned Magic Wand tool. Alternatively, marquee select (keep the boundary as close to the text as you can) will get you something.

Use `Select > Modify > Expand` and add a few pixels to the selection. How much depends on your image, but it doesn't need to be more than 5 pixels, even for a high-resolution image.

Once you have your "slightly larger than the text" selection, Shift-F5 or `Edit > Fill...` and choose `Content-Aware Fill`. This will fill the area with bits of surrounding content, for an excellent "rough view" of what it might look like without the text.

Comment: As a note, `Content-Aware Fill` is only available in CS5 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Marquee select around the text, and fill that area with the background colour. Fastest, messiest way to do it. Polygon Marquee select if Rectangle doesn't work because of the shape.

Comment: Well the background would be a photo, with many different shapes and colours. So I guess I can't fill anything with a background 'colour' isnt'it?

Comment: If you have text overlaid on a photograph (or even a drawing), there is no general way for removing the text (replacing it with the image it was obscuring) unless you have an intact copy of the original, underlying image. And if you *do* have such a copy, what is the question?

Comment: @Scott, I found it a strange question too unless you don't have the originals (as in using watermarked stock photos for mockups)

Answer (score 0):

First select text, with magic wand or lazo or whatever.
Then create a masked group with this selection. 
Copy and paste a region which have similar color into this group and do it again till you match your needs.